# Python System.Windows.Forms browse file dialog window

Tags: python, user-interface, dialog

I would like to import some data from a .txt file.
Right now I am doing it like so:

```
filename = "C:/results/results.txt"
file = open(filename, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

I wondering if there is way to have some dialog box, which will allow picking the right .txt file file, instead of supplying `filename` variable. Like this:

[image]

Is it possible to get this dialog box without some custom python UI module (like tkinter or similar)? Is it possible to get it through System.Windows.Forms for example?

I am using python 2.7.

Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 2):

In this case the path is to use the ironpython, [link](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/ironpythontutorial/dialogs/)

Comment: Hi neiesc. That's precisely what I was trying to avoid: getting some non standard python modules. System.Windows.Forms on the other hand is a standard one.

Comment: @marco i changed the answer, any particular reason for this? is only for the windows program?

Comment: Yes, it's only for the windows program. I checked the link you posted above, and used the "Open dialog" code. Unfortunately I am not getting the same result as shown on that page. This is what I get when I run the code:
http://i59.tinypic.com/i50kcg.jpg
Any reason why?